# Swift animating view height

Tags: swift, animation, constraints

I am trying to chain 2 animations. But can not get the second animation (change of height) working.

1st try:

```
 self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: width, height: 76)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 280, height: 76)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 280, height: 136)
        }
    })
```

2nd one:

```
    self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: width, height: 76)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 280, height: 76)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            var heightConstraint = self.customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 136)
            heightConstraint.isActive = true
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    })
```

Comment: In your first try you are trying to animate customView and then inRentInfoView, but on the second try you are trying to animate customView twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: Typo, corrected it

Comment: Because i tried your first solution and it worked for me